# IAM policy problem I want to attach only one policy and deny others

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-policies

I have created policy like below. I want to allow to CreateRole with snowflake_access policy only. Every time I'm executing the lambda code I can also attach other policies to this role. I don't know why because clearly I have denied other policies and allow only one. Can someone help me with that?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:CreateRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/snowflake-role*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:AttachRolePolicy",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::7882...:policy/snowflake_access",
                "arn:aws:iam::*:role/snowflake-role*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "iam:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::*:role/snowflake-role*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [actions defined by IAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_identityandaccessmanagement.html#identityandaccessmanagement-actions-as-permissions), you will see a table that maps actions to, among other things, resource types and condition keys. For example:

| Action | Resource Type(s) | Condition Keys |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AttachRolePolicy | role* | iam:PolicyARN iam:PermissionsBoundary |
| CreateRole | role* | iam:PermissionsBoundary aws:TageKeys aws:RequestTage/${TagKey} |

Note specifically that the `AttachRolePolicy` action applies to IAM roles only, not to policies. You've indicated a role ARN (*snowflake-role**) and a policy ARN (*snowflake_access*), but only the former is legal here.

The same table entry also indicates that `iam:PolicyARN` is a valid condition key for the AttachRolePolicy action. So, to indicate a policy ARN, you can add a condition key of `iam:PolicyARN`, something like this.

```
{
    "Sid": "sid1",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "iam:AttachRolePolicy",
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iam::*:role/snowflake-role*"
    ],
    "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
            "iam:PolicyARN": "arn:aws:iam::7882...:policy/snowflake_access"
        }
    }
},
```

I'm not sure this resolves all of the problems you have, but I think it's one part of the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much, It's solved my problems <3. Have a good day Sir